# Date entry in php 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Super noob here so apologies if any of this is obvious or on here wrong!

I have a form that creates a voucher. It has a section where I select the valid from and To dates using a date picker and the same for the display from and To.

My php worked on the test server in 5.3 but the 1and1 server has 5.2 and now when I enter a date it just ignores it and add 01/01/1970 (the first date on the date picker).

I fixed this with a few updates which you can see below and I commented out. The weird thing is that now the Valid From and Display From dates get added, but the Valid To and Display To dates stay on 01/01/1970.

Any ideas?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Name'])) {$Name=$_REQUEST['Name']; };
if(isset($_REQUEST['ValidFrom'])) {
    //$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['ValidFrom']);        

    $time = strtotime($_REQUEST['ValidFrom']);  //Added - 10/12/13 - Converts string to Date
    $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$time);  //Added - 10/12/13 - Formats date 
    $myDateTime = new DateTime($date);  //Added - 10/12/13 - Adds date to object

    $ValidFrom = $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');        
};
if(isset($_REQUEST['ValidTo'])) {
    //$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['ValidTo']);

    $time = strtotime($_REQUEST['ValidTo']);  //Added - 10/12/13
    $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$time);  //Added - 10/12/13
    $myDateTime = new DateTime($date);  //Added - 10/12/13

    $ValidTo = $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');      
};
if(isset($_REQUEST['DisplayFrom'])) {
    //$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['DisplayFrom']);

    $time = strtotime($_REQUEST['DisplayFrom']);  //Added - 10/12/13
    $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$time);  //Added - 10/12/13
    $myDateTime = new DateTime($date);  //Added - 10/12/13

    $DisplayFrom = $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');      
};
if(isset($_REQUEST['DisplayTo'])) {
    //$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['DisplayTo']);

    $time = strtotime($_REQUEST['DisplayTo']); //Added - 10/12/13
    $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$time);  //Added - 10/12/13
    $myDateTime = new DateTime($date);  //Added - 10/12/13

    $DisplayTo = $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');        
};
```

Comment: I also tried changing the format of the date to ('yy/mm/dd H:i:s'); but this makes both dates stop working again.

Comment: 1and1 should feel ashamed of themselves for having such an _old_ version of PHP installed. Deplorable.

Comment: haha agree! In fact I just managed to upgrade it to php 5.4 and ive resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1&1 is a real pain in the ass with compatibility. I don't know what code you're using to input (probably simple text inputs) but I would guess it is an issue with their server.

The date 1/1/1970 is the start of the UNIX epoch. It means that at some point your code is getting a value of 0 out of one of the functions.

Could you send a print_r() of $_REQUEST and $_POST so we can see what is going on there? Do you have error and warning reporting on?

Comment: Thanks Cesar, I actually managed to upgrade the php to 5.4 and just used:    };
 if(isset($_REQUEST['ValidTo'])) {
  $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['ValidTo']);
  $ValidTo = $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');